# Cannot get OpenVPN installed - Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: server, vpn, openvpn

hope this is a simple one for you experts. Been trying to get the configuration going for OpenVPN and keep hitting the same wall:

when I enter this command './build-ca', I get the following:

error on line 198 of /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/openssl-1.0.0.cnf
139967340545688:error:0E065068:configuration file routines:STR_COPY:variable has no value:conf_def.c:584:line 198

The commands I have used are from the guide:

```
sudo apt install openvpn easy-rsa
mkdir /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/
cp -r /usr/share/easy-rsa/* /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/
```

then edit /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/vars

```
export KEY_COUNTRY="XX"
export KEY_PROVINCE="XX"
export KEY_CITY="XXX"
export KEY_ORG="Example Company"
export KEY_EMAIL="xx@xx.com"
export KEY_CN=MyVPN
export KEY_NAME=MyVPN
export KEY_OU=MyVPN

cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/
source vars
./clean-all
./build-ca
```

I have used the guide from Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openvpn.html

Been using PuTTY from my Windows 10 system and doing a copy and paste to ensure no typos but not working. Fairly new to Linux server, have been playing around with Ubuntu 16.04 and CentOS 7 but have not had much luck with either.

My goal is to have a Linux Server setup in my home office and allow remote users to be able to access it to upload files, and eventualy have others access data files with tight restrictions, probably via FTP. PureFTP has worked very well but I need remote users to be able to access this server. What am I missing???

Thanks for your help!

Ps, also tried the guide from here:

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/openvpn-secure-server-administration/

But it appears to be missing some steps as it advises to do this:
apt-get install openvpn
nano /etc/openvpn/server.conf But there is no server.conf file!

Comment: Are you trying to install an OpenVPN server or just set up a client?  If the former, and you have no `server.conf`, you have gone badly astray somewhere.

Comment: I used this tutorial to set up my server: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: You left the server name in vars "server"?  Look for the name you used. The tutorial looks pretty similar to the digitalocean one as far as the ./build-ca anyway.

Comment: I'll have a look at the Digital Ocean guide, thanks Organic Marble

Comment: ubfan1, where are you seeing this?

Comment: KEY_NAME=MyVPN  is what is in vars, not KEY_NAME=server, the default. So I'd expect the conf file to have the name MyVPN.conf.

Comment: OK gotcha, will redo based on the DO Guide and test again. Thanks for the quick response folks! Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: That guide worked! Now to the next issue,

Comment: That guide worked! Now to the next issue, when I try to start OpenVPN Options error: Job for openvpn@server1.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status  openvpn@server1.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
It reports this: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in /etc/openvpn/server1.conf:101: server1 (2.3.10)
 I have checked for typos, (my server is server1) Is the 101 a code or the line with the error? I did not see any issues on line 101???

Comment: Finally running! ● openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN connection to server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; enabled; vendor preset:
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-10-18 14:24:29 EDT; 2h 8min ago
     Docs: man:openvpn(8)
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
 Main PID: 4540 (openvpn)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-openvpn.slice/openvpn@server.service
           └─4540 /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-server --status /run/openvpn/s

Comment: All I can say is FOLLOW THE GUIDE - Copy and Paste as much as possible. Check for typos, then check again!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the vars file:
export KEY_ALTNAMES="Anythingyouwish"

And then follow the process for ./build-ca

Good Luck